# How does embedded linux detect file is modified through usb gadget & update files

Tags: linux, usb, usb-mass-storage

I have an embedded linux device running a USB gadget kernel module to make the mmc available to the host PC(such as Windows or Linux).
When I update the file in mmc, it won't sync with host PC unless I rmmod and insmod again. Is there any better way to update new files? And how can I detect a file is modified by host PC? I'm using C programming on my linux device.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(1) There really isn't a better way to update new files. You need to take turns and only access the mmc from Linux or Windows, one at a time.

(2) You can't easily do that.

When you say "When I update the file in mmc", I assume that you have the mmc mounted in the linux device, and are updating files from linux *at the same time* that Windows has mounted the device. I don't think this is advisable. The host (Windows) may cache file and/or directory information from the mmc, and if the embedded Linux changes that information unexpectedly, it may produce errors from the Windows FS, and could corrupt the mmc.

If you want to share files between the embedded Linux and host Windows, and be able to modify them from either OS without taking turns, an alternative solution would be to use the network device gadget and run Samba file sharing on the embedded Linux side to export the filesystem where the mmc is mounted on the Linux side.